# How to get only the active bundles in karaf

Tags: osgi, bundle, state, apache-karaf, karaf

I need a command to get only the active bundles in osgi / karaf,

```
I know that scr:list / osgi:list will list all the bundles irrespective of state. 

Is there any other easy way to check all the bundles are active in karaf?
```

Regards,
Harry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
la | grep -i active
```

where la is a shortcut for osgi:list with list all bundles including system.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
la | grep '| Active    |'
```

Since this will avoid any false positives due to a bundle which has 'active' in its name.